# Inserting list contents into columns instead of rows using Pandas library

Tags: python, pandas

My goal is to add lists into three columns and export to excel. I was successful in adding the lists in rows, but the data would suit better in columns.

I added the data to rows using this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[firstList,secondList,thirdList])

df.to_excel('new.xlsx', sheet_name='first sheet')
```

I am unsuccessful in adding it to columns using this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1' : [firstList],
    'col2' : [secondList],
    'col3': [thirdList]
})

df.to_excel('new.xlsx', sheet_name='first sheet')
```

The output on the code listed above is:
[image]

Here is the desired output:
[image]
Another thing I am trying to do is remove the indexing column as well, but that is less important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all list have the same lengths, use:

```
df2 = df.apply(pd.Series.explode)
```

*NB. If you have string convert first to list:*

```
df = df.apply(pd.eval)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import ast
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda col: col.apply(ast.literal_eval))
df = df.explode(cols)
```

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1' : [firstList],
    'col2' : [secondList],
    'col3': [thirdList]
})

df.explode([firstList,secondList,thirdList])
df.to_excel('new.xlsx', sheet_name='first sheet')

Comment: Running this code gives me this error:

Comment: raise ValueError("column must be a scalar, tuple, or list thereof")
ValueError: column must be a scalar, tuple, or list thereof

Comment: Ran a print(type(firstList)) and it prints: <class 'list'>

Comment: What are the types of the other two lists?

Comment: They are also <class 'list'> as well; going to try updated edit now

Answer (score 1):

Split the list by using the split function and using explode function will assign each value to a separate row

```
#Creating Empty Dataframe
```

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c'])

for i in ['a','b','c']:
df2[i] = df[i].str.split(',').explode().reset_index(drop=True)

df2